# Is it possible to schedule or automate report generation in CSV or XLS report type in Thingsboard PE?

Tags: report, export-to-csv, scheduler, xls, auto-generate

I find the feature **Scheduler event** in Thingsboard PE very interesting, but there are only three types of report **(PDF, JPEG, PNG)** possible to schedule. But it would be interesting to know if there are some ways to schedule **CSV or XLS report types**. May be it is possible to **automate** the CSV or XLS report generation and send it to an email with Scheduler event or in Rule chains.

It would be great if anyone could help me out with this. I would be grateful to every hints and responses.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Thangaraj

Answer (score 1):

For now, it is not possible save reports in other formats.
An alternative can be save report in PDF and send it to a backend process that can parse pdf to csv.

Comment: oh thanks. I hope thingsboard upgraded their features now!